# how to calculate a percentage with multiple comboboxes in VBA User form

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, calculated-field

Hi there I need to give a percentage score for a multipage in a userform in VBA.
as shown below
[image]

I have formatted the combo boxes as follows:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 With Cbx1_1
.AddItem "N/A"
.AddItem "Yes"
.AddItem "No"
 End With

With Cbx1_2
.AddItem "N/A"
.AddItem "Yes"
.AddItem "No"
End With

With Cbx1_3
.AddItem "N/A"
.AddItem "Yes"
.AddItem "No"
End With

With Cbx1_4
.AddItem "N/A"
.AddItem "Yes"
.AddItem "No"
 End With
 OUTBX.Value = " "
 End Sub
```

Now comes the problem after answering the questions, I am looking to include a button named "Calculate" which would result in a percentage in the "ResultBx" that would equal 67%.

The idea is that the calculation would look something like this:

```
 ResultBx.Value=(COUNTIF(Range(Cbx1_1,Cbx1_2,Cbx1_3,Cbx1_4),"=Yes"))/
 ((COUNTA(Range(Cbx1_1,Cbx1_2,Cbx1_3,Cbx1_4)))-(COUNTIF((Range 
 (Cbx1_1,Cbx1_2,Cbx1_3,Cbx1_4)),"=N/A")))
```

I know That I am including Excel code here but I need to "convert" it to VBA

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your button is named `CommandButton1`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a As Long, b As Long

a = IIf(cbx1_1.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(cbx1_2.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(cbx1_3.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(cbx1_4.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)
b = 4 - IIf(cbx1_1.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(cbx1_2.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(cbx1_3.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(cbx1_4.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)
OUTBX.Text = Format(a / b, "00%")

End Sub
```

Or if you prefer:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

OUTBX.Text = Format( _
    ( _
    IIf(cbx1_1.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + _
    IIf(cbx1_2.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + _
    IIf(cbx1_3.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + _
    IIf(cbx1_4.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) _
    ) / _
    (4 - _
    IIf(cbx1_1.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - _
    IIf(cbx1_2.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - _
    IIf(cbx1_3.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - _
    IIf(cbx1_4.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) _
    ), "00%")

End Sub
```